# MVC 5 how to add search functionality into Controller/Create?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 tables as shown below. I have 3 controllers and views. In Payment/Create.cshtml I need to add customer search functionality before creating any payment.

I need to check first the right customer and when I found it I need to add into payment create table and  enter other values and create a new payment. How do I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that Customer field u need to display all customer name means

**In Controller:**

```
     public ActionResult Create()
     {
      ViewBag.CUSTId = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTId", "CustomerName");
      return View();
     }
```

**In View:**

```
     @Html.DropDownList("CUSTId ", String.Empty)
```

You Need Search Method means Just see the following video u il get to know how to do it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slw-gs2vcWo

Comment: Thank you Vinoth, I made it.